# MySQL Database saving 0 values

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, submit

I have a form to take statistics for course registration at my university , one of the fields is the "studentid" connecting the form to the database seems to be successful and the primary field with auto increment is working just fine , however entering the student id and submitting the form fails every time and a new record is added with a "0" value ...

this is the html code

```
     <div class="content">

    <form action="connect-mysql.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" id="form3" name="form3" method="post">

    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#e3e3e3"><center>
        Student ID :
        </center></td>
        <td width="50%" bgcolor="#e3e3e3">
          <span id="sprytextfield1">
          <label for="studentid"></label>
          <input name="studentid" type="text" id="studentid" onblur="MM_validateForm('studentid','','NisNum');return document.MM_returnValue" maxlength="11" />
*<span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span>
        </td>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
$host="fdb7.biz.nf" ;`enter code here`
$username="1662822_db1" ;
$password="421343" ;
$db_name="1662822_db1" ;
$tbl_name="courses" ;
    $dbcon = mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$db_name") ;           

    if (!$dbcon) {
    die('error connecting to database'); }

    echo 'you have connected sucessfully' ; 

// escape variables for security
$studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['studentid']);

$sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid)
VALUES ('$studentid')";

if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
 }
 echo "1 record added"; 
    mysqli_close($dbcon);
  ?>
```

Comment: take out `enctype="text/plain"` in the form.

Comment: have you tried validating what $_POST['studentid'] gets you?

Comment: when you say 'fails everytime' what do you mean

Comment: What is the field type of studentID?  I can imagine it giving you this trouble if it is any type of integer - you may try varchar.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty , I tried that now its saving a number regardless of the number I put for example my input in the form was 20112025060 , in the database 2147483647 similarly for any other number.. the studentid column type is int with a max of 11...does this affect anything ? , thanks

Comment: @JohnnyFaldo meaning it fails to post the values in the form to the database and gives a zero in the database column , however the new problem is as mentioned above

Comment: make it bigint datatype

Comment: @dsimer the field type is INT with a max of 11 characters so int(11)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty datatype = "text" ?

Comment: no the field in mysql table you said its int(11) make it bigint

Comment: By the way, please tell me that isn't your actual database connection info in the post. :p

Comment: @dsimer lol no no ...I got that part right thankfully :P

Comment: Well it looked more...legit?...than most entries. :)

Comment: well the pass is definitely not correct ...I'll be more careful next time though , thanks for all your help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
method="POST"
```

is repeated in the form

Check the studentid this way:

```
$studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['studentid']); echo $studentid;
```

You can print the $sql variable to after setting it.

Comment: I'm not sure using mysqli_real_escape_string on an integer will work.  It will return a string, and MySQL will likely reject the input as an incorrect data type.

Comment: oh ! thanks for pointing the post repetition , sadly the problem remains regardless of the input I place in the form the studentid column saves some random number ... example input= 1234123123 ...saved = 2147483647 
input = 12312312312 saved = 2147483647 ...same number

Comment: @dsimer , that might be the problem ,makes sense . Do you think I should replace it with escape_integer?

Comment: That's because those are bigger numbers than the traditional INTEGER value type can store, try with lower numbers as 123 or 231 or even 9999999, here you can see the INTEGER LIMITS http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: I usually run a conditional with is_numeric() to be sure it can be an integer and then when placing the value force it to int by preceeding it with '(int)' - that will prevent is_numeric() from allowing a float, etc.

Comment: @perodriguezl , thank you very much ...bigint was the correct type ^^' ...thanks again

Comment: @dsimer turns out I needed to define the type correctly ... thanks a lot though :D

Comment: is_int() would do the trick instead mysqli_real_escape_string!